# Create an object via Reflection and pass it to another class

Tags: java

I have two classes

```
Class Application {

 int id
 String applicationName;

  // getter and setter
}
 
Class User{

int id;
String userName
Application app;

public User(Application app ){
   this.application = app;
 }
}
```

Now I receive the JSON data for `Application` like this

```
{ "id" : 123,
  "applicationName": "Slack",
  "type" : "org.example.Application"
}
```

My question is how do I deserialize it ( Application ) into an application Object and pass it to the `User` object using reflection?

**Note:**: In my processing function, I just have `Application` and `User` classes by its fully qualified name `org.example.Application` & `org.example.User` respectively.
How do I deserialize it and create the user object.

Comment: Have a look at [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)), `Class#getConstructor`, and `Constructor#newInstance`.

Comment: @AlexR : I already know about these but if you see .. `Class.forName` will give me the instance of `Class`<?>`, it will not give me the instance of `Application` , while class `User` needs the instance of class `Application`

Comment: Then you just cast the result of `newInstance` to `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialise the JSON to a Java object as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // com.fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-databind

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class class = Class.forName("org.example.Application");
Object application = objectMapper.readValue("{ \"id\" : 123, "applicationName\": \"Slack\",   \"type\" : "\org.example.Application\"}", clazz);
User user = new User(application);
```

You may need to define an interface that org.example.Application implements.

```
public interface General{}


Class Application implements General {


public User(General app){
   this.application = app;
 }


User user = new User((General)application);
```

Comment: Here is the problem, I can not hard code `Application.class`. I just have a fully qualified name like `org.example.Application`

Comment: So you have a class name but not a class definition for org.example.Application and org.example.User? If so you can't. Cannot create a class definition via reflection.

Comment: I have the definitation also but suppose that I can not hardcode `Application.class` during deserialization. I have the fullyQualified name of this class, can we pass that or create the instance from this name ..